# Make a write call update the data in a inmemory cache on all the kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, caching, guava, redis-cluster, consistency

How to make a write call and update the data in a inmemory cache on all the kubernetes pods. It would be better if there is some solution which does not involve maintaining a centralized cache.

Something related to an instance discovery mechanism which updates the data across all the pods.